# Remove an element from an object

Tags: reactjs

My code is,

```
let data={type:1, name:"tye", address:"hbjh454"}
```

I want this object like,

```
let data={ name:"tye", address:"hbjh454"}
```

I need to Remove type from this object

Comment: have you tried `delete data.type` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

```js
let data = { type: 1, name: "tye", address: "hbjh454" };

delete data.type;

console.log(data);
```